# not able to push lightning-web-component in salesforce

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am using this command to push component to salesforce
sfdx force:source:push but nothing happens this issue comes.

Starting SFDX: Push Source to Default Scratch Org

```
14:12:52.362 sfdx force:source:push
ERROR:  EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\PROGRA~1\NODEJS~1\NODE_M~1\npm\bin\sdx_mdpkg_1546245791160'.
14:13:13.673 sfdx force:source:push ended with exit code 1
```

I created my web component with this
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quick-start-lightning-web-components/create-a-hello-world-lightning-web-component

Comment: Can you try running command prompt as System - Admin?

Comment: yeah, I also try with that, having same issue
ERROR:  EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\PROGRA~1\NODEJS~1\NODE_M~1\npm\bin\sdx_mdpkg_1546247431711'.

Comment: Can  you type `sfdx plugins` to see what version of SFDX you are on? You should be on `salesforcedx 45.0.12 (pre-release)` version to use LWC

Comment: salesforcedx 44.11.0

Comment: what to do? Not able to see custom component on Salesforce tab. after pushing web component to salesforce. sfdx force:source:push

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LWC can only be pushed on `salesforcedx 45.0.12 (pre-release)` version of Salesforce DX CLI. You have to update the CLI using the following command.

```
sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@pre-release
```

Once the plugin is updated you will be able to push LWC into any Spring 19 or.

I would also recommend going though this trailhead to have a quick grasp.

Src: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quick-start-lightning-web-components/set-up-salesforce-dx

Comment: one more question, same issue when i remove component from aura folder. and having web component in lws folder.

sfdx force:source:push
=== Pushed Source
No results found

Comment: what to do? Not able to see custom component on Salesforce tab. after pushing web component to salesforce.

sfdx force:source:push
=== Pushed Source
STATE  FULL NAME                                             TYPE                  PROJECT PATH
─────  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────  ────────────────────  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Add    helloWorldComponent\helloWorldComponent.auradoc

Comment: i follow this one https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quick-start-lightning-web-components/create-a-hello-world-lightning-web-component 

but having same issue not able to see helloworld webcomponent on salesforce.

Comment: Might worth asking new question with the code you have written.